# JMeter Test setup(Master & Slave) on Azure VM to trigger 3000 concurrent users

Tags: jmeter

can one share some inputs/links to JMeter(Master & Slave) on Azure VM. What is the VM configuration(Master & Slave) to be used to trigger 3000 concurrent users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We don't know as it depends on the nature of your test plan,number of requests per second, size of requests/responses, number of [pre](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#preprocessors)/[post](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) processors, [assertions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#assertions), etc.

You need to measure it, i.e.

1. Implement your test plan
2. Run the test starting from 1 user and gradually increasing the load up to 3000 at the same time looking at resources consumption via [Azure Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/monitor-vm) or [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test/)

   When any of monitored metrics like CPU, RAM or Network usage starts exceeding reasonable threshold, i.e. 80% of total available capacity take a look how many virtual users were online at this stage using i.e. [Active Threads Over Time](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ActiveThreadsOverTime/) plugin

   - If the number of users is 3000 - you're good to go with this VM
   - If the number of users is less than 3000 - consider either increasing the [size](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/sizes) of the VM or adding a new VM of the current size as the slave (or several machines, depending on how many users you were able to kick off)